# Failed to navigate: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'signature-pad'

Tags: angular, ionic2, signaturepad, ionic3

I am trying to implement angular2 signature pad in my ionic 3 project i am getting error as above my question.
I am following this tutorial [link](https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic-2/). It is working fine in ionic2 but when i try in ionic 3 i am getting error like below

```
Failed to navigate:  Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'signature-pad'.
1. If 'signature-pad' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'signature-pad' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <ion-col></ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <signature-pad [ERROR ->][options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signatur"): ng:///ConformsignModule/Conformsign.html@20:21
'signature-pad' is not a known element:
1. If 'signature-pad' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'signature-pad' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <ion-col></ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      [ERROR ->]<signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplet"): ng:///ConformsignModule/Conformsign.html@20:6
```

> you can get the full code in this like i just trying everything in this  https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic-2/
>
> I think when i use deeplink navigation i am getting this error but when i import my component to app.module.ts everything is working fine

update

here is my .ts file

```
export class Conformsign {

  signature = '';
  isDrawing = false;
  finalData
  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;
  @Input()
  private signaturePadOptions: Object = { // Check out https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad
    'minWidth': 2,
    'canvasWidth': 400,
    'canvasHeight': 200,
    'backgroundColor': '#f6fbff',
    'penColor': '#666a73'
  };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public toastCtrl: ToastController, public holders: Holders, public rest:Rest) {

    this.finalData = this.holders.getData();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Conformsign');
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.signaturePad.clear()
  }

  drawComplete() {
    this.isDrawing = false;
  }

  drawStart() {
    this.isDrawing = true;
  }

  savePad() {
    this.signature = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
    this.signaturePad.clear();
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'New Signature saved.',
      duration: 3000
    });
    toast.present();

     let conformDelivery = {
      order_id: this.finalData.order_id,
      amountpaid:this.finalData.total,
      customername:this.finalData.firstname,
      signature:this.signature,
      user_id:this.finalData.user_id,
      customer_id:this.finalData.customer_id
    }

  }

  clearPad() {
    this.signaturePad.clear();
  }

}
```

here is my .html

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="title">Please draw your Signature</div>
  <ion-row [ngClass]="{'drawing-active': isDrawing}">
    <ion-col></ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col></ion-col>

  </ion-row>
  <button ion-button full color="danger" (click)="clearPad()">Clear</button>
  <button ion-button full color="secondary" (click)="savePad()">Save</button>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col></ion-col>
    <ion-col width-80>
      <img [src]="signature"/>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col></ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please add the code that show where you are using options. Hardly anybody will look at a whole projects code. The essentials parts should be included in the question directly instead of a link to an external resource.

Comment: i have updated my question with the code @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Where does `<signature-pad` come from? Why do you think it has an `options` property?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i think it is comming from this plugin `npm install angular2-signaturepad --save`

Comment: after installing that plugin i am getting an angular2-signaturepad folder in my nodemoduels and inside that i got signature_pad.js inside that

Comment: You need to add the module to imports of `AppModule` or your feature module where you're using the signaturepad module

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer of course i have imported this `import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';` in my app.module.ts file

Comment: are you using `Conformsign.module.ts` for lazy loading? @MohanGopi

Comment: @suraj yes i am using the conformsing.module.ts file for lazy loading part

Answer (score 8):

I was facing this issue also. I solved this issue by going through comments on the original post by devdactic https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic-2/

A guy named Ka mok pointed me to something

IF you are using the signature pad in a component . in my case am using it in a farmers component, the component usually have a farmer.module.ts file. So just import the signature pad module and everything should work fine

e.g

farmer.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FarmerPage } from './farmer';
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FarmerPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(FarmerPage),
    SignaturePadModule // this saved my life
  ],
})
export class FarmerPageModule {}
```

farmer.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Lastly make sure you also import the module in app.module.ts

I hope this helps someone. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, just in case some noob (like myself) comes here trying to figure it out for Ionic 4, you need to add it into the import section of your app.module.ts. When installing the plugin from command line it will be auto added to Providers but you also need to manually included in the imports! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the module to imports

```
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';

@NgModule({
  imports: [/* BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes), ... */,
      SignaturePadModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

where `AppModule` is the same module that also contains in `declarations: [...]` the component where you are using the signature pad.

Comment: this my app.module.ts file `imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    SignaturePadModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ]` but still i am getting this same error

Comment: And `Conformsign` is in `declarations: [...]` of the same `NgModule`?

Comment: No in ionic 3 i am using Deeplink navigation so i dont need to import `conformsign` or any other component in app.module.ts file

Comment: i am able to navigate to any other pages in my project except when i go to the `conformsign` page i am getting this error

Comment: It's not related to navigation, it's related to `options`. Either no registered component with the selector `signature-pad` is registered or it doesn't have an `options` input.

Comment: yes it is working when import all the component in my app.module.ts file

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last comment. Could you make it work? What did you have to change?

Comment: @if you see my question i have said the in ionic 2 it is working fine ofcourse in ionic 3 when i import all the pages/component in my app.module.ts file i am not getting any error everything is working file when i use deep link navigation i am facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Import the `SignaturePadModule` in `Confirm.module.ts` since you are using ionic 3.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ConfirmSign
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(ConfirmSign),
        SignaturePadModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ConfirmSign
    ]
})
export class ConfirmSignModule { }
```

Comment: I tried the above answer but i am getting this error now `Failed to navigate:  Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/panini/checkingv3/node_modules/signature_pad/signature_pad.js'`